# how to cancel multiple alarm using other activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-alarms

Create note `Activity` from where `Alarm` trigger! and `Alarm` delete code in other `Activity`,it delete only last trigger `Alarm` means if **3** `Alarm` are created and I want to delete `Alarm` **1** it deletes but when the time of `Alarm` **1** reaches it trigger while it already deleted and it wont trigger other `Alarm` **2 and 3**, on static broadcast id it trigger only last alarm for example alarm **3** trigger delete code in other activity if it delete on using same pending intent in other activity how can i use the pending intent which use trigger alarm in my delete alarm activity

```
 AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
                    String alertTitle = mTitleText.getText().toString();
                    intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.alert_title), alertTitle);
                   // broadcastCode++;
                    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), broadcastCode, intent,  PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                    alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calender.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
                    cv.put(mDbHelper.TIME, timeString);
                    cv.put(mDbHelper.DATE, dateString);
public void delete(int id)
{

    db.delete( DbHelper.TABLE_NAME, DbHelper.C_ID + "="+id, null);
    db.close();

    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), CreateNote.broadcastCode, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The PendingIntent needs to be created exactly as it was when you started the AlarmManager.

Use `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` instead of `0` when creating the PendingIntent to cancel the alarm. FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT is equal to the constant `134217728`, not `0`.

Comment: it works but for single alarm created in list, if the multiple alarm are created in list from example total **5** alarm are created and to i delete alarm **1** which created at first it delete from list but it trigger on time when its time reaches, and   alarm **2,3,4,5** are not trigger,

Comment: Individual alarms are identified by their `REQUEST_CODE` and the original `Intent` that's wrapped into a `PendingIntent`. You have to make sure the `REQUEST_CODE` (which you seem to be saving into a database) and the `Intent` match the values you supplied when setting the alarm.

Comment: you mean to say REQUEST_CODE and Intent must be save in database

Comment: Are you setting the id for every alarm?

Comment: @SimranjeetSingh i'm using broadcast code increment which give it new id

Comment: Check for your id, if it is coming out different everytime the alarm hits. I am using the time set as the id for every alarm.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, _id, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: which type of id i replace there sir

Comment: i'm using there same id which i use to  create alarm, it work for single alarm, for multiple alarm it does not work

Comment: sir Simrantjeet Sing please help i'm stuck on problem from weak ago